# Как настроить отправку формы с лендинга

Tags: javascript, php

### На сайте есть две формы:

**первая** - для заказа консультации,
 **вторая** - для оформления подписки.
Подскажите, каким образом можно настроить ***отправку*** ***писем мне на почту*** с данного лендинга, с данными, который ввел пользователь.
При оформлении подписки, нужно просто чтоб в теме письма был заголовок, указывающий, на то, что пользователь хочет оформить подписку.
Заранее благодарен.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Погуглите - вот и все дела. Заранее не за что.

Answer (score 1):

1. Качаем и устанавливаем PHPMailer (*вкратце: это PHP-библиотека для отправки почты, устанавливается путём копирования папки на сервер, подключается и настраивается путем создания конфигурационного файла*)
2. Гуглим как его настроить, вводим SMTP-данные своей почты в настройки (для этого создадим php файл, пропишем там настройки и функцию отправки, пример приложил в шаге №5)
3. На странице с формой код формы должен выглядеть примерно так:

   ```
   ....
   <form action="sendmail.php" method="POST">
       <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Ваше имя">
       <input name="email" type="text" placeholder="Ваша почта">
       <input name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Ваш телефон">
       <input name="details" type="text" placeholder="Детали заявки">
       ....
       <input type="submit" value="Оставить заявку">
   </form>
   ....
   ```

   тут важно обратить внимание на method='POST' (способ как будем отправлять и следовательно получать данные сервером), action="sendmail.php" (страница на которую будем отправлять данные с формы, её мы создадим в следующем шаге) и name каждого input-a для того чтобы указать его в серверной части, таким образом получив его значение.
4. Создаём файл sendmail.php в нём пишем что-то вроде:

   ```
   <?php
       $name = $_POST['name'];
       $email = $_POST['email'];
       $phone = $_POST['phone'];
       $details = $_POST['details'];

       require_once('mail.class.php'); //подключим настройки phpmailer, этот файл мы создадим на 5 шаге

       $message_data = array(
          'to'      =>  'почта@приема.заявок', 
          'to_name' =>  'Новая заявка от '.$name,      
          'text'    =>  $name.', '.$email.', '.$phone.','.$details
       );

       $mailer = new mail; //класс из файла mail.class.php который мы подключили выше

       $sendmail = $mailer->send($message_data);

       $answer = 'EMPTY';

       if ($sendmail == 0)
       {
           $answer = 'Заявка оставлена!';
       } else {
           $answer = 'Ошибка! Письмо не было отправлено.';     
       }

       echo $answer;
   ?>
   ```
5. Файл mail.class.php (так уж и быть, распишу настройки PHPMailer-a) должен выглядеть примерно так:

   ```
   <?php
   class mail{

       private $smtp_data = array(
           "host" =>  'ЗАПОЛНИТЬ', // SMTP сервер
           "debug" => 0,   // Уровень логирования (0 выкл, 1 - вывод ошибок, 2- полный лог)
           "debugoutput"=>  'html',    //формат вывода лога, если включено логирование
           "auth" =>  true,    // Авторизация на сервере SMTP. Если ее нет - false
           "port" =>  ЗАПОЛНИТЬ,   // Порт SMTP сервера
           "username" =>  'ЗАПОЛНИТЬ', // Логин на SMTP сервере
           "password" =>  'ЗАПОЛНИТЬ', // Пароль на SMTP сервере
           "fromname" =>  'ЗАПОЛНИТЬ', // Отображаемое имя отправителя
           "replyto" =>  array(
               "address" => 'ЗАПОЛНИТЬ',   // адрес почты для ответа
               "name" =>  'ЗАПОЛНИТЬ'  //отображаемое имя владельца ящика
           ),
           "notification" => array(
               "address" =>  'ЗАПОЛНИТЬ',  // Почта оповещения админа (не оповещать оставить пустым)
               "name" =>  'ЗАПОЛНИТЬ'  //отображаемое имя владельца ящика
           ),
           "secure" =>  'ЗАПОЛНИТЬ',   // Тип шифрования. Например ssl или tls
           "charset" =>  'UTF-8',  //кодировка отправляемых писем
           "verify" =>  '0'    // Верификация сертификата. 0 -выкл, 1 - вкл (выключить при возникновении ошибок связанных с SSL сертификатами при отправке)
       );

       private $mail_content = array( 
           'title' =>  'ЗАПОЛНИТЬ',
           'header' =>  '',
           'footer' =>  ''
       );

       private function fullText($text)
       {
           if(!empty($text))
           {
               return $this-> mail_content['header'] . $text . $this->mail_content['footer'];
           }
           else
           {
               die("Отсутствует текст письма");
           }
       }

       public function send($message_data)
       {                
           require_once('C:/..ПУТЬ../PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');                 

           $mail = new PHPMailer;
           $mail-> isSMTP();
           if($this-> smtp_data['verify'] == 0) {
               $mail-> SMTPOptions = array('ssl' => array(
                   'verify_peer' => false,
                   'verify_peer_name' => false,
                   'allow_self_signed' => true
               ));
           }

           $mail-> Host = $this-> smtp_data['host'];
           $mail-> SMTPDebug = $this -> smtp_data['debug'];
           $mail-> Debugoutput = $this-> smtp_data['debugoutput'];
           $mail-> SMTPAuth = $this-> smtp_data['auth'];
           $mail-> Port = $this-> smtp_data['port'];
           $mail-> Username = $this-> smtp_data['username'];
           $mail-> Password = $this-> smtp_data['password'];
           $mail-> SMTPSecure = $this-> smtp_data['secure'];
           $mail-> CharSet = $this-> smtp_data['charset'];
           $mail-> setFrom($this-> smtp_data['username'], 
           $this-> smtp_data['fromname']);
           $mail-> addReplyTo($this-> smtp_data['replyto']['address'], 
           $this-> smtp_data['replyto']['name']);

           if(!empty($this-> smtp_data['notification']['address'])) {
               $mail-> addAddress($this-> smtp_data['notification']['address'], 
                                  $this-> smtp_data['notification']['name']);
           }

           $mail-> addAddress($message_data['to'], $message_data['to_name']);
           $mail-> Subject = $this-> mail_content['title'];
           $mail-> msgHTML($this-> fullText($message_data['text']));
           $mail-> AltBody = strip_tags($this-> fullText($message_data['text']));

           if (!$mail-> send()) {
               die("Mailer Error: " . $mail-> ErrorInfo);
           } else {
               return 0;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Удачи вам в решении задачи! Выглядит всё громоздко и трудно, но на самом деле достаточно легко. Гугл будет верным союзником при возникновении каких либо трудностей и вопросов на этапах выполнения описанных мною шагов.
P.S.: Описанный мной способ подразумевает что у вас будет зарегистрирован почтовый ящик ДЛЯ ОТПРАВКИ ПИСЕМ на любом почтовом сервисе (google/mail/yandex/...) и письма будут отправляться с него при помощи PHP+PHPMailer на нужные e-mail адреса (в вашем случае это ваш собственный e-mail адрес)

Answer (score 0):

В файле index.html

```
<form method="POST" action="send.php">
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="text" name="mail">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Файл send.php

```
<?php
$subject = "Заголовок письма";
$text = $_POST['email']."\nТекст: ".$_POST['vopros'];
$address = "admin@stite.ru";    
mail($address, $subject, $text, 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
echo "Отправлено";
```